# How can I set the Page.User Property in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

This is mostly a theory question, for example if I wanted to create my own alternative to forms authentication.

Comment: I thought forms authentication is easily extended to meet the most extravagant needs. Why do you want to use your custom module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write your own authentication module - see this [excellent article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479391.aspx) that explains how to write an ASP.NET authentication module supporting basic & digest authentication.

In case, you are thinking of only forms authentication scheme then you really don't have to write one. The in-build Forms Authenticate module is quite extensible (and offers a lot of flexibility).

Answer (score 2):

`Page.User` just returns `Page.Context.User`, which should be set in a handler for `HttpApplication.AuthenticateRequest` via module or `global.asax`. You can provide a custom implementation of `IPrincipal`, which could then return a custom implementation of `IIdentity`.

For example:

```
public class App : HttpApplication
{
    public App()
    {
        AuthenticateRequest += App_AuthenticateRequest;
    }

    void App_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var cookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];

        if (cookie == null) return;

        var userData = GetUserData(cookie.Value);
        var userIdentity = new MyIdentity(userData);

        Context.User = new MyPrincipal(userIdentity);
    }

    private string GetUserData(string value)
    {
        try
        {
            var ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(value);
            return ticket == null ? null : ticket.UserData;
        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
            Response.Cookies.Remove(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After some googling, I found [this blogpost](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ploeh/archive/2008/02/10/pageuserpopulationfromcustomauthenticatorsforaspnet.aspx). It describes quite well how to do it. Basically you need to create a custom HTTP module and handle the `OnAuthenticateRequest` event of `HttpApplication` object.