# Assigning Name property of the Page User property

Tags: asp.net, anonymous, loginview

I'm a newbie to asp.net and this is a theoretical question but could someone please elaborate the following:-

**[msdn]**

The **AnonymousTemplate** property specifies the content template to display to Web site users when they are not logged in to the Web site. This template is displayed when the **Name** property of the **Page User** property is null.

I want to know how does the name property is assigned and all the background tasks that runs to achieve it.
I'm not getting sufficient information and have looked at this [How can I set the Page.User Property in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6407689/how-can-i-set-the-page-user-property-in-asp-net)

Thanks!!

Comment: It is handled automatically by the runtime during the authentication process. For what purpose do you need to manipulate the Page User properties?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the way to change the `Name` property value is to authenticate as a user.

Make it simple: `AnonymousTemplate` will be shown when the user is not yet logged in.

Comment: Actually i wanted  to know the background process.How does it happens, that is name property gets changed as soon as user is authenticated??Thanks..

Comment: Since you're using .Net function, I'm not sure if such detailed information available. But yes, once the user is authenticated, it will be stored in `User` property, not `Name`. Check [HttpContext.User](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user(v=vs.100).aspx) and [Form Authentication Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fw3ef80(v=vs.100).aspx)